# Accidentally deleted "id" field solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I accidentally deleted id field from solr. What to do now?

```
{
    "add-field" : {
     "name":"id",
     "type":"string"
    }
}
```

Not working too. Core not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running in SolrCloud mode? If not, edit the managed-schema directly on the disk under the core directory, then restart Solr.

If you're running in cluster / cloud mode, you can first use the `downconfig` command to download the current configuration, the [use `upconfig` to upload](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/command-line-utilities.html#CommandLineUtilities-Uploadaconfigurationdirectory) the edited configuration.

`zkcli.sh` is located under `server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh` by default.

Comment: Perfect. Tried this already. It worked. Was in solrcloud mode, used zk to download the configset, edited the configset, added the id field details manually and uploaded. It worked. Thanks a lot though!!